# Code is not executed after the jquery ajax complete event

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have tried to execute some code inside the ajax complete event but it doesn't work on the page load event , but it works perfectly in the onchange link event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function() {
         // Handle the beforeSend event
        },
        complete: function() {
            // Handle the complete event
            $("#customfields_1 :input").filter(function() {
                return $.trim(this.value).length === 0;
            }).closest("td").hide();
        }
       // ......
    });
});
```

Comment: Could be because you're missing a URL to send the request to?

Comment: @adeneo  it doesn't work on the page load event , but it works perfectly in the onchange link event

Comment: @adeneo can you be more specific

Comment: No, not really! You need to send the request somewhere, otherwise how will it work ?

Comment: If you send a letter you need to put an address on the envelope...

Comment: @adeneo yes it is , i don't know why becouse i'm using an existing MVC application , so all what i have to do is to execute the function in the load event

Comment: I actually was under the impression that you did'nt post the entire function, and left part of it out, and it was more of a joke? You do have an `url: 'mypage.php'` and a `type: 'POST'` parameter etc. otherwise it will never work?

Comment: hahaha i sweer a god that it works perfectly in the onchange event but not in the onload

Comment: @adeneo can you please send me what i have missed in the .ajax method

Comment: I don't really know what adress you need to send the request to, or what type of request you are sending. All I can say is look at the examples in the [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and see that they have a url parameter, which is the script that receives the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://foo.bar.com/some.json',  // this is the important part
        beforeSend: function() {
         // Handle the beforeSend event
        },
        complete: function() {
            // Handle the complete event
            $("#customfields_1 :input").filter(function() {
                return $.trim(this.value).length === 0;
            }).closest("td").hide();
        }
       // ......
    });
});
```